# Receiving email with attachment in android

Tags: android

I want to create one application which receive email with attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use JavaMail API for this purpose. this link might be helpful for you http://www.roseindia.net/javamail/

but make sure you use the javamail jar file for android because the main jar of javamail is for java and there is an android compatible javamail jar also exist.

Comment: Hey thanks....pls tell me some details...how javamail API use? roll of .jar file?

Comment: you need to use jar for it. you should read the tutorial. there you find all details. and you can also see the folloing link here from the first reply you can download the necessary android javamail jar. also there is an example how to send mail. But since you have to attach file you should go through the tutorial. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-a